# How to install real time patch on Embedded Linux version 3.16.0

Tags: linux, embedded, patch, real-time

I have a microprocessor that runs the embedded linux version 3.16.0-rc3 (armsdk@debian, gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)). I wanted to install a real time patch, but I did not find the one for my linux version. (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/) Can I install a newer/older version?

I have a real-time application with a function that needs to be carried out every 100 ms. But the kernel can interrupt my software, therefore I frequently have up to 1000 ms latencies. Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I guess it is not possible to install it for this version.